# Powershell Exit Event now failing in Win10 update 1607

Tags: powershell

I have used something like the following Register-EngineEvent to catch the closing of the console window in which a script is running.  This started working in Powershell V3 and has worked until I just installed the anniversary update to Windows 10 (1607).

The event still triggers for Ctrl-C and if typing "exit" on an open console but not if clicking the "X" or "close" on the window as it used to.

```
Register-EngineEvent PowerShell.Exiting -Action { write-host "Exiting"; start-sleep -s 2 }
```

Any ideas on how to work-around this?  For example, are there ways to start Powershell with older engines to continue the old behavior?

The [Microsoft docs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849967.aspx) show it should be working for V5 for what that is worth.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

"Any ideas on how to work-around this? For example, are there ways to start Powershell with older engines to continue the old behavior?"

This is how you can run an older version:

```
PowerShell.exe -Version 4
```